# One user database, two applications at different servers

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter

I currently run an Rails app on a single VPS with it's own MySQL database. This database also contains the users table. We are currently building a second application which should have the same users. If one registers for either, he has an account for both.

However, the problem is that this second (PHP) application  must be hosting at another location. What are the best practices here? Can I directly connect to the external database without causing a big delay? Should I sync them? Create a API at the first?

I'm searching for the most maintainable method possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow the second host access to the first MySQL server. The best practices (*as far as I'm aware*) to do this would be to create a new user account, give it the required privileges to the users table, **only** allow access to it from the IP or domain of the second host and using a secure password. You would run this query on the MySQL server:

```
GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.users TO 'mynewuser'@'123.123.123.123'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecurepassword';
```

Needless to say you would replace 'mydatabase.users' with your database and table name, 'mynewuser' with the username of the user you want to have access (you can put anything here, the user will be automatically created), '123.123.123.123' with the IP or domain name of your second server and 'mysecurepassword' with a good and long password, preferably randomly generated.

Your second server would now be able to connect to the MySQL server and have `ALL` privileges (you can change that to what ever privileges it needs) on the mydatabase.users table.

[MySQL 5.6 GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html)
[Greensql.com on MySQL remote access best practices](http://www.greensql.com/articles/mysql-security-best-practices)

To minimize the small performance penalty I would refrain from creating multiple MySQL connections (Try to use as few as possible, preferably just one). I'm not 100% on the following, but I'm pretty sure it would be a great idea to reduce the amount of separate queries you execute as well. Instead of running 10 separate inserts, run one insert with multiple `VALUES` segments, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id, name) VALUES
    (0, 'mia'),
    (1,'tom'),
    (2,'carl');
```

I'm sure [MySQL Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) would also be of considerable help reducing the speed penalty

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the database from the second application.
but the delay for the connection will always be there.
Another thing is you have to consider about the security as the database will be accessible to the world. You can restrict the connection only to the second web server.
To reduce the delay, you have options like having a memcached or other caches so that you dont have to hit the database again and again.
You can have a mysql replication and have the main database as master and setup another mysql in the second application server and make it as slave.
The Second server's mysql syncs with the master and all the write queries (update, insert, delete etc.) should go to master. This should reduce the database load.